# Rails: How do I select the current user instead of all the users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make it automatically pull up the current users name when I go to the user profile page. Like I click on the "message me" button and instead of pulling all the users on the site, I want it to pull automatically the user I am looking at.

Right now when I press the "message me" button it pulls up all the users and I have to choose which user to send the message. What can I do? I can use `<%= user.name %>` to pull up the user but that isn't going to help me.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%= @user.name%>">Message Me</button>`

```
<%= f.collection_select (:recipients, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>
```

Full code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <%= form_for :conversation, url: :conversations, html: { class: "" } do |f| %>

    <div class="panel2-signup">
        <div class="panel-body-signup">

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>

    <div class="form-group">
        To <%= f.collection_select (:recipients, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>

      Subject:
        <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control" %>

      Message:
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Type your message here", rows: 4  %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the db info

```
    class CreateMailboxer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up    
  #Tables
    #Conversations
    create_table :mailboxer_conversations do |t|
      t.column :subject, :string, :default => ""
      t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
      t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
    end    
    #Receipts
    create_table :mailboxer_receipts do |t|
      t.references :receiver, :polymorphic => true
      t.column :notification_id, :integer, :null => false
      t.column :is_read, :boolean, :default => false
      t.column :trashed, :boolean, :default => false
      t.column :deleted, :boolean, :default => false
      t.column :mailbox_type, :string, :limit => 25
      t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
      t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
    end    
    #Notifications and Messages
    create_table :mailboxer_notifications do |t|
      t.column :type, :string
      t.column :body, :text
      t.column :subject, :string, :default => ""
      t.references :sender, :polymorphic => true
      t.column :conversation_id, :integer
      t.column :draft, :boolean, :default => false
      t.string :notification_code, :default => nil
      t.references :notified_object, :polymorphic => true
      t.column :attachment, :string
      t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
      t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
      t.boolean :global, default: false
      t.datetime :expires
    end    


  #Indexes
    #Conversations
    #Receipts
    add_index "mailboxer_receipts","notification_id"

    #Messages  
    add_index "mailboxer_notifications","conversation_id"

  #Foreign keys    
    #Conversations
    #Receipts
    add_foreign_key "mailboxer_receipts", "mailboxer_notifications", :name => "receipts_on_notification_id", :column => "notification_id"
    #Messages  
    add_foreign_key "mailboxer_notifications", "mailboxer_conversations", :name => "notifications_on_conversation_id", :column => "conversation_id"
  end

  def self.down
  #Tables   
    remove_foreign_key "mailboxer_receipts", :name => "receipts_on_notification_id"
    remove_foreign_key "mailboxer_notifications", :name => "notifications_on_conversation_id"

  #Indexes
    drop_table :mailboxer_receipts
    drop_table :mailboxer_conversations
    drop_table :mailboxer_notifications
  end
end
```

The **ConversationsController.rb**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :get_mailbox

  def new
  end

    def index
    end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients]) 
        if 
            conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
            flash[:notice] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
            redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Error. Message was not created"
            redirect_to new_conversation_path
        end


  end


  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user).order("created_at ASC")
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)

  end


  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)

  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

        def delete
        @mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|
        conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(deleted: true)
    end
    flash[:notice] = 'Your trash was cleaned!'
        redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
    end


  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body,recipients:[])
  end

      def get_mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
                 if  @user = current_user
            @post = current_user.posts.build
        else
        end
                  if  @user = current_user
            @post = current_user.posts.build
            @purchased = Sale.where(buyer_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
      @sales = Sale.where(seller_email: current_user.email).order("created_at DESC").order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
        else
        end
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're not showing the "message me" button, nor explaining which action is serving this "user profile page" you're talking about, nor which action/page the "message me" button is on and so we have no way of knowing the mechanics behind "the user I am looking at". This is an impossible question to answer right now.

Comment: @smathy, the message me button is `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%= @user.name%>">Message Me</button>`

Comment: Improve your question, don't add it as a comment. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and probably [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @smathy, I went ahead and updated the question

Comment: You just pasted that line into the middle of your question with no explanation or context. As you can see, your question has been put on hold, it will be closed unless you improve the quality as per the guidelines I linked you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your action filters it looks like you are using the `devise` gem for user management.

To get the current authenticated user in devise you can use the helper method `current_user`.

Comment: `<%= f.collection_select (:recipients, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>` put `current_user` in this?